# Error con thymeleaf en Spring

Tags: java, html, web, spring-boot, spring

An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")

He revisado mi sintaxis y parece estar correcto pero me sigue saliendo el error, no se que estoy haciendo mal ayuda por favor

```css
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.web.app.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Titulo app web con Spring");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title th:text="${titulo}"></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 th: text ="${titulo}"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué los espacios en `th: text ="${titulo}"`?

Answer (score -1):

al request mapping no le has indicado el vervo que quieres usar (get, post, put, delte, etc...) en tu caso es una consulta debería ser get

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/index",method= "get")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Titulo app web con Spring");
    return "index";
}
```

otra opcion sería usar la anotación GetMapping

```
@GetMapping("/index")//como tiene solo un argumento me tomo la libertad de quitar lo de path
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Titulo app web con Spring");
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no es correcta. El error es claramente de sintaxis por el mensaje  _during template parsing_ y se ve claramente en donde está por los espacios de más que agregó. Nada tiene que ver con no especificar el método en`@RequestMapping`. Si consultas la documentación, cuando no se especifica el method  en `@RequestMapping`, simplemente queda implícito que ese endpoint puede solicitarse con cualquier verbo http. Checa [este post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#2-requestmapping----the-http-method).